# Best practice when using Reverse-DNS Package Notation and vanity domains?

Tags: naming-conventions, package, naming, reverse-dns

When using reverse-DNS package notation (such as `com.apple.ostype`), what should one do when the domain name is designed to be read in its entirety (such as `http://read.me`)?

Strictly following the standard results in a package which, while syntactically correct, loses the desired overall identity—conversely, not following the standard retains identity but loses syntactical clarity (`me.read.MyPackage` versus `read.me.MyPackage`).

What is the common practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common practice is:
`me.read.MyPackage`